# How to deploy react from build folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a project with a Ratpack server on the back end and a react admin section. When I run my project my React app gets built into my build folder, inside this folder I have a static directory with a css folder a js folder and an index.html file.

I am now confused as to how I can deploy these files, I would like to have a html page which could serve the application up, is it possible to simply include my js and css files into this html page and get the app to work?

Then I could render the html template server side when the user hits a certain link. Is this possible / the right way to do things? Sorry i'm new to React.

Comment: Put it on your http server using apache2, nginx... or many different others.

Comment: @NguyenThanh Then how do you redirect all the routes to index.html?

Comment: With apache2, use rewrite mode, with nginx, setting up vhost like this:
https://gist.github.com/homanp/4e49daedddabfa5b8321